# How to schedule BI servers restart every day?

Tags: oracle, etl, oracle12c, schedule, obiee

I use Oracle BI 12c and I am facing this strange problem while using it. The thing is there is an ETL process that transfers data from one database to another and that database(dwh) is used for OBIEE.

Even though transfer succeeds and data is present in tables for yesterday, creating analysis on that day returning no data. The only way I get it is restarting BI servers through enterprise manager.

So my question is how can I schedule BI servers to restart every day in the morning or is there any other solution for this problem?

**EDIT**
Today while I traced log messages when   created an analysis, I noticed two error messages repeating. one is the following:

> POST
>   /bisearch/rest/BISearchEventService/postEvent?eventType=web_catalog&eventSubType=web_catalog_object_updated&objectKey=%2f&tenantID=ssi&ownerID=18446744073709551615&sessionID=0000&locale=en_US

and the other one is

> [43065] The connection with Cluster Controller
>   ::ffff:10.11.10.19.34713 was lost.

I guess the last one is the issue. Have somebody faced it?

Comment: Do you use caching? Are you caching empty result sets??

Comment: As I see from EM, BI server cache is disabled

Comment: That doesn't really make sense then. Have you traced the queries? Have you investigated what's actually happening? Because without more information it's hard to say anything more pertinent. And I would NOT go down the road of restarting just because the root cause of the issue hasn't been found!

Comment: I looked at logs but there is nothing that is related to this. Problem still exists and I have to restart it every day. There is no way to do this automatically?

Comment: By the way, logs show some nqserrors which are not found by consistensy checker of rpd administration. What could that mean?

Comment: What exact errors?

Comment: like 'logical table must be a descendant of the root logical table ....'  for two tables. But I don't use that tables when creating that analysis and they are not in the subject are I am using

Comment: What @Chris said. Don't restart your servers just because it happens to work around an issue.

You said you get no data returned for the current day – is that the no results message? What happens if you then filter it to yesterday? Do you now get results?

What does the query log say? Is it going to database?

Comment: [43065] The connection with Cluster Controller error was the only one when I tried to run the analysis for the current day.  Query Log shows Query status as 'Successful completion'. 
Yes, by no data returned for the current day I mean No Results message. When the same query is executed in database it shows the records. That is the thing I cant understand.

Comment: @jackohug, yes I get results when I filter for yesterday and the days before the current day. However for the current day OBIEE can't fetch data that is currently present in databse.